# "Metaphoring road trips with life and its success", how to write this statement correctly?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, headlinese

I have written an article which compares life and its success with road trip but I am getting trouble in deciding perfect heading. So please tell that is the above statement correct or it can be improved.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: *metaphor* is a noun and you cannot use that as verb there! And the question is opinion based.

Comment: @MaulikV : Thanks for reply Maulik. And I have edited the question. Is it answerable now?.

Comment: Life - A successful journey (don't use metaphor; that's what I shall advise).

Comment: that is good. but readers wont understand from heading that I have compared Life with Road trip, any idea on how to do it would be a great help..

Comment: If there isn't a better verb, then it's perfectly acceptable to invent a new verb from a noun. You will probably be wrong and be corrected, but people will often understand your meaning. In this case, there are many verbs that mean what you are trying to say.

Comment: Perhaps you could actually **use** a metaphor: "Life is a road trip" or "Success and failure: life as a road trip"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just draw the metaphor directly in your heading?

**Life is Like a Road Trip** 
?

Then people will understand that your article is going to explain this metaphor, yes?

Another word for "metaphoring" (which is a verb-ed noun and not a real word) would be "to liken" or "to relate"  So, if you wanted to rewrite your title directly, I would say "Relating road trips to life and its success"

I'll go on to say that shorter headlines are more impactful, as long as you don't lose meaning. For example, this headline could be improved simply by rewording it to say "Relating road trips to success in life"  or better still "Life is like a Road Trip".

Comment: Very direct and clever answer. I got your point and will think of a title which keeps my heading clean and short. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like "Life is Like A Series of Road Trips"  Just make the title a metaphor itself.  The readers will understand once they read the paper.  YOu want to choose something to capture their attention and WANT to read the paper.  DOn't be TOO technhical in your title choice.  GOOD LUCK!!